# Wire-framing tools to use your own custom assets and styleguide

Tags: design, wireframe, tools, mockup

I'm looking for a way or a wireframing tool that has a way to create high fidelity mockups using custom UI assets that have been already created and custom defined grid to match your own design style guide EXCEPT FOR PHOTOSHOP OR HTML/CSS. Tools i've used so far only allow the default controls to be used and the mockups are lo fidelity. the aim of doing this is too essentially bridge the gap between wireframing and creation of final mockups

Comment: Hi there, in your question you ask for wireframing tools, but then say it's for high-fidelity mock-ups, although not the same, you question is a little vague.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for product recommendations, it is not a UX problem that can be solved with a correct answer. Please see this Stackexchange blog post about such questions: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to create high fidelity mock ups, I don't believe that there is a system where you can input your style guide, and have the system use that as a basis.

Personally, I use illustrator with [Flinto](http://www.flinto.com) as well as [Pixate](http://www.pixate.com) to create my (interactive) mockups